# Read remote registry in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, registry

I am able to read the registry key on a local machine using the following code

```
key = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\somename1\\somename2")
path=  _winreg.QueryValueEx(key, "PATH")[0]
```

I would like to do the same for a remote machine, i.e read the registry entries on a remote machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to connect to the remote computers registry and access it via that object. See the [ConnectRegistry function on the doc page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/_winreg.html).

e.g.,

```
rem_reg = ConnectRegistry("remotename", HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE)
rem_reg.OpenKey( ...
```

ADDED

As long you you have a valid UNC name, have permissions, and have not been blocked by a firewall along the way you should have able to do what you want to the remote registry

Comment: Is it necessary that the remote machine should be in the same domain?